# RDFa breadcrumb code error possibly due to OGP?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, rich-snippets, rdfa, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I'm getting a strange error when validating a structured data implementation for breadcrumbs.

This is the code that we have for the breadcrumbs:

```
<header class="breadcrumbs">
    <div xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
       <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a class="breadcrumbs" href="#" rel="v:url" property="v:title">All Copenhagen Apartments</a> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 
       </span>
       <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a class="breadcrumbs" href="#" rel="v:url" property="v:title">2 bedroom apartments</a> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 
       </span>
       <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a class="breadcrumbs" href="#" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Vanløse</a> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 
       </span>
       <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
        <a class="breadcrumbs" href="#" rel="v:url" property="v:title"><b>Villa Vanløse apartment</b></a>
       </span>
    </div>
</header>
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.all-copenhagen-apartments.com%252Fvilla-vanloese-apartment-cph15%252F&filter=RICH_SNIPPETS_BREADCRUMBS)
 is the link to the error on Google's Structured Data Testing Tool.

The error I'm getting is this:

```
url [Unspecified type]:

is not a known valid target type for the http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#url property.
```

In the [Screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOwk1GjRLg5O2a0e50F--ijt6JQcoUwRreQB/image.png) there are also references an implementation of OpenGraph Protocol (`OGP`) that we have in the head:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Copenhagen apartment with balcony and garden"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.all-copenhagen-apartments.com/villa-vanloese-apartment-cph15/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.all-copenhagen-apartments.com/galleri/15/01.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="product"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="all-copenhagen-apartments.com"/>
```

When I try to validate only the breadcrumb code everything looks good, I can't understand why there would be a problem between the breadcrumb code and the OGP code in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool only gives this error if it fetches the code via URL. If you check the very same code by inputting it directly (e.g., check via URL, then edit something irrelevant, then check again), no error is reported.

So this is likely a bug in the tool.

Someone has the [same problem over on Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/82092/17633), where the Google employee John Mueller [also thinks](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82322/17633) that it’s a bug.